# Nginx web-dav 409 Conflict CRUD php API

Tags: php, nginx, crud

Trying to configure nginx for proxy HTTP CRUD requests to fastcgi

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name api.example.dev;

    dav_methods  PUT DELETE;

    dav_access group:rw all:r;
    create_full_put_path on;

    index index_dev.php;
    set $root_path '/var/www/api/public';
    root $root_path;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index_dev.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.api.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index_dev.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HOST $host;
        fastcgi_param DESTINATION $http_destination;
        fastcgi_param OVERWRITE $http_overwrite;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
    }
}
```

On PHP side i've got phalcon php-framework.
Witch works fine with simple GET/POST requests. And routers from framework can handle PUT, DELETE methods. But when i try to make simple PUT method request nginx return me 409 Conflict error with that configuration above.

I can't find any suggestions for that case and how to pass web_dav methods to php from nginx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is in the context of plain nginx WebDav, but may be useful to your PHP situation as well.  I've found that you'll get a 409 if you try to specify a destination parent folder instead of the complete destination including the filename. Example:

Setup:

```
$ echo "test" >> ~/test.txt
$ cat ~/test.txt
test
```

Bad test:

```
$ curl -X PUT -d `cat ~/test.txt` http://localhost:8080/
<html>
<head><title>409 Conflict</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>409 Conflict</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.5.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Good test:

```
$ curl -X PUT -d `cat ~/test.txt` http://localhost:8080/test.txt
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/test.txt
test
$
```